# Backbone events

Tags: jquery, css, backbone.js, coffeescript

Hi I was wondering how I handle the remove hover state using backbone and js

currently I have

```
events: {
  "hover .info"   : "hover"
},

hover:(e) =>
  $(e.currentTarget).css("background-color", "#333")
```

I was wondering how I would handle the event where i move my mouse away from the element with class .info

If i do standard coffee script inside to do this inside the hover: event handler it requires 2 hovers for it to work.

I basically want to imitate

```
$(".info").hover(
    function() {
       $(this).css("background-color", "#333")
    },
    function() {
       $(this).css("background-color", "#F3F")
    },
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a version of [`hover()` that takes one callback function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2):

> **Description:** Bind a single handler to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer enters or leaves the elements.

This is the version of `hover` that will get used by Backbone. So you could handle this with [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and a couple CSS classes instead of directly messing around with the `css`:

```
hover:(e) =>
  $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('dark-gray')
```

The default `#F3F` color would be set on the element by default and you'd have:

```
.dark-gray {
  background-color: #333
}
```

in your stylesheets. If you cannot for some reason use `toggleClass`, you'd have to bind to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` individually.

Comment: It's worth noting that the direction is passed to the handler function. `hover(e) {console.log(e.type);} // outputs 'mouseenter' or 'mouseleave'`

Answer (score 27):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> Calling `$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)` is shorthand for:
>
> `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`

So I think the best way to handle this with Backbone is just to set two events (sorry, I don't believe in CoffeeScript):

```
events: {
  "mouseenter .info"   : "hoverOn",
  "mouseleave .info"   : "hoverOff"
},

hoverOn: function(e) { ... },
hoverOff: function(e) { ... }
```

Alternatively, you could use the [single argument syntax](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2), which takes one function and calls it on both in and out - this works well with `.toggle()` and `toggleClass()`.

Comment: This answer works much better when not using a simple toggle. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In this precise example, however, you should really use [css :hover pseudo class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#useraction-pseudos) instead of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not an action link then you can following css : `pointer-events:none`